# slideshow on extra monitor?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, screensaver, slideshow

I'm looking for a slideshow style application for windows that I can apply to one monitor on a multi-monitor system.  I want to simulate it being a photo frame, in rotating pictures etc.  I also need the other monitors to be unaffected, except maybe a tray icon allowing some options.

I'd like it to keep working even when the PC is locked, which might make this the hardest part, and might not even be possible.

I found some shareware called AutoWallpaper, which seems like it might work out well for just rotating pictures every so often, but A) I'm cheap an it costs money, and B) would love to have transitions between images as well.

It seems that most slideshow screen savers have a nice look to them (google's screen saver that works by pulling in images from picasa etc is pretty cool) but I can't use it at the same time I'm actually using the PC.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [FoxSaver](http://www.foxsaver.com/), a [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/personal.html) [plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5276) that turns your browser into screensaver. It pulls [pictures](http://www.foxsaver.com/public/latest) from their website and/or your computer. The main reason I use this is when I teach class. Before class and on breaks I just Maximize that instance of Firefox with Foxsaver running, When I want my presentation back up I just minimize it and start teaching.

You can use the [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) screensaver for when the computer is locked, it puts different pictures on each monitor a feature I really like, and if you point [Foxsaver](http://www.foxsaver.com/) to the same directory you put your [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) [screensaver](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=19542) pictures in it's practically the same thing.

You could even add pictures of delicious waffles and ponies.

[image: Pancakes with Syrup Traps]

[image: OMG PONIES]

Comment: Hmm I like foxsaver, with the extent it says foxsaver on it, and there is a tab bar that won't go away when I do full screen. It's very close to doing what I'm looking for.

Comment: @zimmer62 you can disable the logo in the options. Maximize Firefox on the monitor you want to display it on start foxsaver and then hit the button on the bottom to make it go full screen.

Comment: I must have some other plugin or tab bar causing full screen to still show me an auto hiding tab bar, just a little bit of it.   I was going to full screen, and thanks for the option to turn off the logo.

this will work!

Answer (score 1):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) can do this! Transitions and all!

Don't think it's possible for it to happen when the PC is locked, however, sorry. You may wish to look into alternative methods of locking - perhaps just input using [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com)?

Comment: I think I'm going to have to use two methods then.  I'm pretty sure a standard screen saver will work when the PC is locked.  I'll just have run as normal, using a screen saver that will do slideshows.

I'll take a look at irfanview.

Comment: Screensavers do work when your PC is locked, don't they! Forgotten about that, good thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be CPU overkill, but what about open office impress /or msoffice powerpoint? If you make the sideshow and set it to run on a particular screen with auto next slide it should work except for the "when locked part".

I think you can even convert powerpoints to self executing files. If powerpoint doesn't allow this, there are certainly third party utilities.